# undefined method `original_filename' ERROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to create an image uploader storing pictures in a database, here the db schema:

```
owner, type, filename, binary_data
```

All string type, except for binary_data, which is binary type.

My files:

View

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "createnew"}, {:mulstipart => true}) %>
  <%= hidden_field "image", "owner", :value => session[:login] %><br/>
  <%= text_field "image", "filename",  :size => 20 %><br/>
  <%= file_field "image", "image_file" %><br/>
<%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
```

.rb file (source of the error)

```
def image_file=(input_data)
  self.filename = input_data.original_filename
  self.type = input_data.content_type.chomp
  self.binary_data = input_data.read
end
```

Controller

```
def createnew
  @image = Image.new(params[:image])
  if request.post? 
    @image.save
  end
end
```

Anyone know what's wrong with my code? thanks!

Comment: Are you using `paperclip` as an attachment uploader gem?

Comment: `{:mulstipart => true}` typo in `mulstipart`?

Comment: @gmile: no I'm not using any gems, trying to do this from scratch.

Comment: @jdoe: oh sorry I typoed it on purpose to test something, in Ruby 3 multipart is always set to true or something so you don't have to explicitly set it. I changed it back and it doesn't make a difference

Comment: hi, i am used to form_for but does form_tag need to be passed in like this: `:html => {:multipart => true}`

Comment: @SamJohnson Is `input_data`  a `IO` or `File` object with `read` permission I guess you need to `open` the file in read mode not sure on this though did this long back could you please confirm

Comment: undefined method `original_filename' ERROR?... the error is not clear.. Please paste full error detail/logs

Answer (score 1):

You wrong on with `multipart` data. Please change your form into:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "createnew"}, :method => :post, :multipart => true do %>
```